# Lie derivative: Leibniz rule proof

Tags: derivatives

How can I prove $\mathcal{L}_v(\omega\wedge\alpha) = (\mathcal{L}_v\omega)\wedge\alpha + \omega\wedge(\mathcal{L}_v\alpha)$ ?

Comment: By writing down the definitions and cranking through the ordinary product rule. (Look up "Cartan's magic formula.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show $L_v (A\otimes B)= L_v A\otimes B+A\otimes L_v B$  for any tensor $A, B$. Recall the definition of $L_v$ using derivation of flow, you will find this is simply an advanced version of $\frac{d}{dt}(fg)=(\frac{d}{dt}f) g+f (\frac{d}{dt}g)$.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not familiar with the concept of tensors. What I have is some basic knowledge about differential forms + the definition of the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_v\omega = \frac{d}{dt}(\textrm{exp}vt)^*\omega\bigg|_{t=0}$

Comment: @user1135859 This is enough for your proof. What you need is to differentiating $\exp vt^*(\omega\wedge \alpha)= (\exp vt^*\omega\wedge \exp vt^*\alpha)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! But I'm still struggling with this.

Now I have 
$$\mathcal{L}_v(\omega\wedge\alpha)=\ldots=\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}\left((\exp tv)^*\omega \;\wedge\;(\exp tv)^*\alpha \right)\bigg|_{t=0} $$
But I don't know how to carry out the differentiation. Do I need some kind of a chain rule? I know that
$$ {\rm d}(\mu \wedge\nu) = {\rm d}\mu\wedge\nu \;\pm\;\mu\wedge {\rm d}\nu$$
But since in my case there is not simply "$\rm d$" but "$\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}$" I do not know to apply this.

Comment: @user1135859 Use the chain rule of $\frac{d}{dt} f(t)g(t)$ for *whatever product* of *whatever stuffs* (only bi-linearity matters)